# How to extract values from xml column in a table using SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

I am trying to extract values from a XML column in a table in SQL Server.  I have this table `InsuranceEntity` with columns `InsuranceEntity_ID` and `EntityXML`.

The `EntityXML` column has values such as:

```xml
<insurance insurancepartnerid="CIGNA" sequencenumber="1" 
           subscriberidnumber="1234567" groupname="Orthonet-CIGNA" 
           groupnumber="7654321" copaydollaramount="1" />
```

How can I extract `subscriberidnumber` and `groupnumber` from this `EntityXML` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XQuery methods `.nodes()` and `.value()` to the rescue.

You may need to adjust data types. I used a generic `VARCHAR(20)` across the board.

**SQL**

```
--DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (InsuranceEntity_ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, EntityXML XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (EntityXML) VALUES
(N'<insurance insurancepartnerid="CIGNA" sequencenumber="1"
           subscriberidnumber="1234567" groupname="Orthonet-CIGNA"
           groupnumber="7654321" copaydollaramount="1"/>');
--DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT InsuranceEntity_ID
    , c.value('@subscriberidnumber', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS subscriberidnumber
    , c.value('@groupnumber', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS groupnumber 
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY EntityXML.nodes('/insurance') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
| InsuranceEntity_ID | subscriberidnumber | groupnumber |
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|                  1 |            1234567 |     7654321 |
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```